# Can I fake calling methods in Ruby tests?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I'm running some tests on my Ruby code, but the method I'm testing calls a function in an external library responsible for sending push notifications. I want the calls it makes to be 'faked', so they don't actually get called. It'd also be helpful if they could return a standard response, or yield with a standard response. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please, add some example code.

Comment: you are looking for a [mock object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object). There's plenty of possibilities in Ruby to do so : rspec-mocks, rr, mocha, and probably many others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can fake calling methods in Ruby tests. What you are looking for is creating so called **mock code**. It is entirely possible to return anything you want from such mock code.
You can create an identifier in Ruby which **shadows** another one - so for example you can create your own function shadowing one already existing in a library.
Google for the items written above in **bold** or ask more specific question, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The [VCR gem](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) makes it very easy to save your test suite's HTTP interactions and run them deterministically. That would be my suggested approach.

You can also, as others have pointed out, stub the method you are calling and manually specify its response. If you were using [rspec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#setting-responses), this would mean to add a line above the HTTP call in the test. Something along the lines of:

`allow(Pusher).to receive(:message).and_return( "An object of your liking" )`